# sqlx: Unsupported type _badge of column #6 ("badges")

Tags: sql, postgresql, rust, rust-sqlx

I'm using Rust's [sqlx](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx) crate, and trying to perform the following:

```rs
query_as!(User, r#"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name ILIKE $1"#, name)
```

Note that I am using **Postgresql**.

I am confronted with this error:

```rs
error: unsupported type _badge of column #6 ("badges")
  --> src\services.rs:16:11
   |
16 |     match query_as!(User, r#"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name ILIKE $1"#, name)
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::sqlx_macros::expand_query` which comes from the expansion of the macro `query_as` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Here are my `User` and `Badge` definitions:

```rs
#[derive(sqlx::Type, Serialize, Deserialize, Display)]
#[sqlx(type_name = "badge")]
pub enum Badge {
    Sponsored,
    Founder,
    Developer,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct User {
    uuid: Uuid,
    date_joined: DateTime<Utc>,
    name: String,
    badges: Vec<Badge>,
    articles: Vec<String>,
    followers: i64,
}
```

My table looks like this:

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| uuid | uuid |
| date_joined | timestamp_tz |
| followers | bigint |
| badges | badge[] |
| name | text |
| articles | text[] |

I've even tried to implement the `PgHasArrayType` trait for the `Badge` struct:

```rs
impl PgHasArrayType for Badge {
    fn array_type_info() -> PgTypeInfo {
        PgTypeInfo::with_name("_badge")
    }

    fn array_compatible(ty: &PgTypeInfo) -> bool {
        true
    }
}
```

**Note**: Using the non-macro version of `query_as` works for some reason.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too late for answer but perhaps it will help someone else. Problem happens because compile-time sqlx query checker can't infer custom type (like Badge in this case) without help. When `query` macro used, you must declare which type is returning like:

```
SELECT badge AS "badge: Vec<Badge>" FROM users;
```

If you use `query_as` you can just put underscore instead of type and compiler will infer it:

```
SELECT badge AS "badge: _" FROM users;
```